# Issue when using Mutate and Case_when in a loop

Tags: r, filter, subset, posixct

I have a data frame with all the information from a racing yacht in that day (lg) and I wish to create variable that tells me what race the yacht was in. This race start and finish time are in a separate df (RaceInfo).  I can filter by race time, but there is a changeable amount of races per day so it may need a loop.

**Some Data**

```
lg <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18897, 18897, 18897, 18897, 
18897, 18897, 18897, 18897, 18897, 18897), class = "Date"), Time = structure(c(1632725883, 
1632725884, 1632725885, 1632725886, 1632725887, 1632725888, 1632725889, 
1632725890, 1632725891, 1632725892), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Lat = c(43.2760531, 43.276059, 43.276065, 43.2760708, 
43.2760766, 43.2760858, 43.276095, 43.2761, 43.276105, 43.2761095
), Lon = c(6.619109, 6.619136, 6.619163, 6.6191932, 6.6192235, 
6.6192488, 6.619274, 6.6192988, 6.6193235, 6.6193532), Awa = c(-7.1, 
-7.12, -7.15, -6.57, -6, -6.2, -6.4, -5.28, -4.15, 0.25), X = 1:10), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the yachts onboard data.

**More Data**

```
RaceInfo <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18897, 18896), class = "Date"), 
    RaceStartTime = structure(c(1632738480, 1632751560), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), RaceNum = c("1", "2"), RaceFinishTime = structure(c(1632751520, 
    1632753000), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c("event.2", 
"1"), class = "data.frame")
```

In the RaceInfo df it tells us the start and finish time of each race, as mentioned before there could be many races and I need to assign a new variable in the lg df as lg$RaceNum based on the times given in the RaceInfo df.

My closes attempt is this but loops are a weak point in my game.

```
for (i in RaceInfo$RaceNum){
      
      lg <- lg %>%
        mutate(Racenum = case_when(
          lg$Time >= (subset(RaceInfo$RaceStartTime, RaceInfo$RaceNum == i)) &
            lg$Time <= (subset(RaceInfo$RaceFinishTime, RaceInfo$RaceNum  == i)) ~ i))
      
    }
```

But this only returns the last number in the loop

Comment: Please fix your data. `–>` is the wrong assignment operator (you want `<-`) but, more importantly, the second `dput` output is incomplete. I think you can just use a data.table non-equi join or `foverlaps`.

Comment: Consider `merge` (cross join) + `subset` if data is relatively small to moderate in size: `lg <- merge(lg, RaceInfo, by=NULL) |> subset(Date >= RaceStartTime & Date <= RaceEndTime)`

Comment: Deleted. I dont want to merge the data sets particulary unless it is the only way.  Just hoping to create a new variable in ```lg```.  I am sure this is possible and quicker using merge but your answer does not give me the result I am after. Could you help me further? Thanks again

Comment: Whoops! What if you adjust `Date` to `Time` and `RaceEndTime` to `RaceFinishTime`?

Comment: Your example data is not useful because clearly the boat was not in one of the two races. I'm confident that you should do a non-equi join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods `mutate` and `case_when` are really to assign calculated columns within a data frame and not specifically for subsetting data frame itself.

Instead, consider [`dplyr::filter`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html) (similar to `base::subset`) even [`dplyr::between`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/between.html) and collect your iteration results to build a data frame list. Then, `rbind` results at end. To subset by unique values, see `by`

```r
df_list <- lapply(RaceInfo$RaceNum, function(i)      
      dplyr::filter(
          lg,
          dplyr::between(
              Time,
              RaceInfo$StartTime[RaceInfo$Racenum == i],
              RaceInfo$RaceFinishTime[RaceInfo$Racenum == i]
          )
      )
)

final_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)
```

But as mentioned above, if your data is manageable with small set of distinct `RaceInfo`, consider a cross join with filter:

```r
final_df <- dplyr::full_join(lg, RaceInfo, by = character()) %>%
    filter(lg, between(
                 Time,
                 RaceInfo$StartTime[RaceInfo$Racenum == i],
                 RaceInfo$RaceFinishTime[RaceInfo$Racenum == i]
               )
    )
```